# How can I delete the previous values and add new values from Json with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this html code part

```
 <div id="prt">
         <select name="selectPrt" class="span12" onchange="sta_callPRT();">
          <option value="noPrt">Choose one vehicle.</option>
          <option value="prt1">PRT 1</option>
          <option value="prt2">PRT 2</option>
          <option value="prt3">PRT 3</option>
          <option value="prt4">PRT 4</option>
          <option value="prt5">PRT 5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span6">
           <div class="section">
            <div class="sectionTitle">
              <h3>Vehicle Info</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
<div id="state"><strong>State:</strong> </div>
          <div id="freeSeats"><strong>freeSeats:</strong></div>
          <div id="battery"><strong>battery:</strong></div>
          <div id="totalDistance"><strong>totalDistance:</strong></div>
          <div id="location"><strong>Location:</strong></div>
          <div id="estimatedTime"><strong>estimatedTime"</strong></div>
          <div id="estimatedDistance"><strong>estimatedDistance:</strong></div>
          <div id="speed"><strong>speed:</strong></div>
```

And this Javascript

```
function sta_callPRT(){

    $.getJSON('PRTInfoGenerator.php', function(json){

        $.each(json, function(key, value) {

       if(key=="state") {
          //$('#state').empty();
          //document.getElementById("parameters").appendChild(divTag);
          $('#state').append(value);
                      }
       if(key=="freeSeats") {
          $('#freeSeats').append(value);
        }
       if(key=="estimatedDistance"){
        $('#estimatedDistance').append(value);
       }
        if(key=="estimatedTime"){
        $('#estimatedTime').append(value);
       }
        if(key=="battery"){
        $('#battery').append(value);
       }
        if(key=="speed"){
        $('#speed').append(value);
       }
        if(key=="location"){
          $.each(json.location, function(par_key, par_value) {

        $('#location').append(par_key+': '+par_value+'  ');
      });
       }
       if(key=="totalDistance"){
        $('#totalDistance').append(value);
       }
    });

  });
  }
```

I want to write the vehicle values randomly in html.I have also php code to produce random values for vehicles.When I select a vehicle, it shows some values but in the second selection the new values are added to the end of the first.How can delete the previous values, and add the new values when new selection is made?
For example this is first selection in the web page;

```
State: Running
freeSeats:0
battery:95
totalDistance:8541
Location:x: -5 y: 34
estimatedTime:15
estimetedDistance:809
Speed:18
```

This is second;

```
State: RunningRunning
freeSeats:04
battery:9540
totalDistance:85411848
Location:x: -5 y: 34 x: 84 y: -70
estimatedTime:15269
estimetedDistance:809513
Speed:1818
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the JSON that's returned?

Comment: Do you mean you want to clear the contents of your divs each time the js runs?

Comment: @SomeSillyName Yes I want to clear div values but how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the divs each time...

```
function sta_callPRT(){
     $('#state, #freeSeats, #battery').empty();

     $.getJSON('PRTInfoGenerator.php', function(json){
           ...
```

Comment: I used your code but when appending new values, I also write State, battery and the others.

Answer (score 0):

Move the prefix text to outside the divs like `freeseats: <div id="freeSeats"></div>` and
use `$('#freeSeats').text(value)` instead of  `$('#freeSeats').append(value);`
appending will append whats already there but text will replace the value instead.

to change the text in the strong tags though you would want to use `$('#freeSeats strong')` but I recommend not using strong tags and use a style attribute on your div/divs instead.

here is your updated code then:

```
<div id="prt"> 
          <select name="selectPrt" class="span12" onchange="sta_callPRT();">
          <option value="noPrt">Choose one vehicle.</option>
          <option value="prt1">PRT 1</option>
          <option value="prt2">PRT 2</option>
          <option value="prt3">PRT 3</option>
          <option value="prt4">PRT 4</option>
          <option value="prt5">PRT 5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span6">
           <div class="section">
            <div class="sectionTitle">
              <h3>Vehicle Info</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          State:<div id="state"></div>
          freeSeats:<div id="freeSeats"></div>
          battery:<div id="battery"></div>
          totalDistance:<div id="totalDistance"></div>
          Location:<div id="location"></div>
          estimatedTime"<div id="estimatedTime"></div>
          estimatedDistance:<div id="estimatedDistance"></div>
          speed:<div id="speed"></div>
```

and the script:

```
function sta_callPRT(){

$.getJSON('PRTInfoGenerator.php', function(json){

    $.each(json, function(key, value) {

   if(key=="state") {
      $('#state').text(value);
                  }
   if(key=="freeSeats") {
      $('#freeSeats').text(value);
    }
   if(key=="estimatedDistance"){
    $('#estimatedDistance').text(value);
   }
    if(key=="estimatedTime"){
    $('#estimatedTime').text(value);
   }
    if(key=="battery"){
    $('#battery').text(value);
   }
    if(key=="speed"){
    $('#speed').text(value);
   }
    if(key=="location"){
      $.each(json.location, function(par_key, par_value) {

    $('#location').text(par_key+': '+par_value+'  ');
  });
   }
   if(key=="totalDistance"){
    $('#totalDistance').text(value);
   }
});
```

`

Comment: But this time State, battery and the other text arent shown.Just the values are shown.

Comment: you can do this then `freeseats: <div id="freeSeats"></div>`